# iOS tap to focus

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I used this code to achieve Tap-to-Focus in iOS custom camera App, but it isn't working. Here's the code

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touchPer = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    var focus_x = touchPer.locationInView(self.view).x / screenSize.width
    var focus_y = touchPer.locationInView(self.view).y / screenSize.height

    if let device = captureDevice {
        if(device.lockForConfiguration(nil)) {
            device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus

            device.focusPointOfInterest = CGPointMake(focus_x, focus_y)
            device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.ContinuousAutoExposure
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about it isn't working?  What errors are produced?  What is the expected behavior?  What is the actual behavior?

Comment: I touch at a point. and focus should be at that point. but there is no effect. it isn't focusing at that point. instead it is always in the infinity focus. That's the problem. @David

Comment: Have you walked through it to insure both ifs are taken?

Comment: Yes. I put a println() after each if. they are going through ifs.

Comment: Why is my question Down voted?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With a `videoView: UIView` displaying the video, and `cameraDevice: AVCaptureDevice`, the following seems to work for me:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touchPoint = touches.first as! UITouch
    var screenSize = videoView.bounds.size
    var focusPoint = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.locationInView(videoView).y / screenSize.height, y: 1.0 - touchPoint.locationInView(videoView.x / screenSize.width)

    if let device = cameraDevice {
        if(device.lockForConfiguration(nil)) {
            if device.focusPointOfInterestSupported {
                device.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint
                device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.AutoFocus
            }
            if device.exposurePointOfInterestSupported {
                device.exposurePointOfInterest = focusPoint
                device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.AutoExpose
            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I had to swap the `x` and `y` coordinates, and remap the `x` coord from 1 to 0 instead of 0 to 1 — <s>not sure why that should be the case but it seems to be necessary to get it to work right (though it's a little tricky to test it too)</s>.

Edit: [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) explains the reason for the coordinate transformation.

> In addition, a device may support a focus point of interest. You test for support using focusPointOfInterestSupported. If it’s supported, you set the focal point using focusPointOfInterest. You pass a CGPoint where {0,0} represents the top left of the picture area, and {1,1} represents the bottom right in landscape mode with the home button on the right—this applies even if the device is in portrait mode.

In my example I had been using `.ContinuousAutoFocus` and `.ContinuousAutoExposure`, but the documentation indicates `.AutoFocus` is the right choice. Oddly the documentation makes no mention of `.AutoExpose`, but I'm using it in my code and it works fine.

I also modified my example code to include `.focusPointOfInterestSupported` and `.exposurePointOfInterestSupported` tests — the documentation also mentions using the `isFocusModeSupported:` and `isExposureModeSupported:` methods for a given focus/exposure mode to test whether it is available on a given device before setting it, but I assume if the device supports the point of interest modes then it also supports the auto modes. It all seems to work fine in my app.

Comment: device.focusMode = AVCptureFocusMode.ContinuousAutoExposure is wrong. Should be "ContinuousAutoFocus"

Comment: Even easier, you could use captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint if you're using a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer class

Comment: Refer to my answer for a Swift 3 version of this answer.

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3.0 Solution**

Converted Cody's answer into a working solution with Swift 3.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touchPoint = touches.first! as UITouch
    let screenSize = cameraView.bounds.size
    let focusPoint = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.location(in: cameraView).y / screenSize.height, y: 1.0 - touchPoint.location(in: cameraView).x / screenSize.width)

    if let device = captureDevice {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            if device.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported {
                device.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint
                device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.autoFocus
            }
            if device.isExposurePointOfInterestSupported {
                device.exposurePointOfInterest = focusPoint
                device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.autoExpose
            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()

        } catch {
            // Handle errors here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You should read Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1385853-focuspointofinterest) on `focusPointOfInterest`, which says three important things:

> 1. Setting a value for this property does not initiate a focusing operation. To focus the camera on a point of interest, first set this property's value, then set the focusMode property to autoFocus or continuousAutoFocus.
> 2. This property's CGPoint value uses a coordinate system where {0,0} is the top left of the picture area and {1,1} is the bottom right. **This coordinate system is always relative to a landscape device orientation with the home button on the right, regardless of the actual device orientation. You can convert between this coordinate system and view coordinates using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer methods.**
> 3. Before changing the value of this property, you must call lockForConfiguration() to acquire exclusive access to the device’s configuration properties. Otherwise, setting the value of this property raises an exception. When you are done configuring the device, call unlockForConfiguration() to release the lock and allow other devices to configure the settings.

Here is an implementation which does all of that:

```
// In your camera preview view    
@objc private func cameraViewTapped(with gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
    addFocusIndicatorView(at: location) // If you want to indicate it in the UI

    // This is the point you want to pass to your capture device
    let captureDeviceLocation = previewLayer.captureDevicePointConverted(fromLayerPoint: location)

    // Somehow pass the point to where your AVCaptureDevice is
    viewDelegate?.cameraPreviewView(self, didTapToFocusAt: captureDeviceLocation) 
}


// In your camera controller
func focus(at point: CGPoint) {
    guard let device = videoDevice else {
        return
    }

    guard device.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported, device.isExposurePointOfInterestSupported else {
        return
    }

    do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()

        device.focusPointOfInterest = point
        device.exposurePointOfInterest = point

        device.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
        device.exposureMode = .continuousAutoExposure

        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different to the other earlier answers?

Comment: @AshleyMills The accepted answer does not mention `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.captureDevicePointConverted(fromLayerPoint:)` - and even does so in a clumsy manual way instead. This is Swift 4, the accepted answer is in Swift 2. In addition, this answer has sources, and follows Swift style conventions / best practices. I do not see why you thought this would warrant a downvote.

Answer (score 8):

```
 device.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint
 device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.AutoFocus
 device.exposurePointOfInterest = focusPoint
 device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.ContinuousAutoExposure
```

I don't why this works, but it did.

Answer (score 5):

The better way to set focus point of interest:

- first calculate the point of interest:

  ```
   let devicePoint: CGPoint = (self.previewView.layer as!  AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint(gestureRecognizer.locationInView(gestureRecognizer.view))
  ```
- after that set the focus point of interest :

  ```
  let device: AVCaptureDevice! = self.videoDeviceInput!.device

      do {
          try device.lockForConfiguration()

          if device.focusPointOfInterestSupported && device.isFocusModeSupported(focusMode){

              device.focusPointOfInterest = devicePoint
              device.focusMode = focusMode
          }

          device.unlockForConfiguration()

      }catch{
          print(error)
      }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5.0 version**

```
// The back camera as default device
var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice? {
    return AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
}

// The camera view.
var cameraView: UIView!

// The layer that contains the camera output
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

// The focus square view - the yellow one ;)
var squareFocusView: UIView

// User taps on screen to select focus
@IBAction func tapToFocus(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // make sure we capture one tap only
    if (sender.state == .ended) {
        
        guard let captureDevice = captureDevice else {
            return
        }
        
        let tappedFocusPoint = sender.location(in: cameraView)
        
        // we need to move the focus point to be the center of the tap instead of (0.0, 0.0)
        let centerX = tappedFocusPoint.x - (squareFocusView.frame.size.width / 2.0)
        let centerY = tappedFocusPoint.y - (squareFocusView.frame.size.height / 2.0)

        let focusPoint = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
        
        // we need to remap the point because of different coordination systems.
        let convertedFocusPoint = previewLayer.captureDevicePointConverted(fromLayerPoint: focusPoint)
        
        do {
            // changing focusMode and exposureMode requires the device config to be locked.
            try captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
            
            if (captureDevice.isFocusModeSupported(.autoFocus) && captureDevice.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported) {
                captureDevice.focusPointOfInterest = convertedFocusPoint
                captureDevice.focusMode = .autoFocus
            }
            
            if (captureDevice.isExposureModeSupported(.autoExpose) && captureDevice.isExposurePointOfInterestSupported) {
                captureDevice.exposurePointOfInterest = convertedFocusPoint
                captureDevice.exposureMode = .autoExpose
            }
            
            // unlocks device config
            captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
            
        } catch {
            // handle error here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the methods in the right order:

```
if(device.lockForConfiguration(nil)) {

    device.focusPointOfInterest = CGPointMake(focus_x, focus_y)
    device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus

    device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.ContinuousAutoExposure
    device.unlockForConfiguration()
}
```

Set the point of interest before setting the focus mode else the focus will be made on the previous point of interest.

The same apply for `exposurePointOfInterest`.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 :

```
   public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    var touchPoint = touches.first as! UITouch
    let cameraView = cameraViewController.view
    var screenSize = cameraView!.bounds.size
    var focusPoint = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.location(in: cameraView).y / screenSize.height, y: 1.0 - touchPoint.location(in: cameraView).x / screenSize.width)
    
    
    
    
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                                             for: .video, position: .unspecified)
        
        do{
            try device?.lockForConfiguration()
            
            if device!.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported {
                        device!.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint
                device!.focusMode = AVCaptureDevice.FocusMode.autoFocus
                    }
            if device!.isExposurePointOfInterestSupported {
                        device!.exposurePointOfInterest = focusPoint
                device!.exposureMode = AVCaptureDevice.ExposureMode.autoExpose
                    }
                    device!.unlockForConfiguration()
        }catch{
            
        }
           
  
            
        
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the provided answers that let's you focus/expose an area/object at specific point, if this object has moved away, or the camera view changed, at this moment we need to set the focusMode back to .continuousAutoFocus and the expose mode back to .continuousAutoExposure to let the system handle the focus/expose

First, we need to observe the subject area changes notification:

```
cameraDevice.isSubjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = true
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setDefaultFocusAndExposure), name: .AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange, object: nil)
```

And configure the camera device when notified:

```
@objc private func setDefaultFocusAndExposure() {
        guard let cameraDevice else { return }
        try? cameraDevice.lockForConfiguration()
        if cameraDevice.isFocusModeSupported(.continuousAutoFocus) {
            cameraDevice.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
        }
        if cameraDevice.isExposureModeSupported(.continuousAutoExposure) {
            cameraDevice.exposureMode = .continuousAutoExposure
        }
        cameraDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
}
```

Finally, don't forget to remove the observer, for me I do it in the deinit:

```
deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```